# Getting records relative to current date in timezone GMT+8

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I wanted to create a report that generate yesterdays records relative to current date in Manila time. Result of the query is wrong until 8AM in Manila time.

I tried subtracting 1 day in current date and convert it in Asia/Manila timezone.

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE date_field >= current_date at time zone 'Asia/Manila' - interval '1 day'
AND date_field < current_date at time zone 'Asia/Manila'
```

If today's current date time in manila is 2019-05-25 1AM

My expected result is records from '2019-05-24 00:00:00' - '2019-05-24 23:59:59'

But what I've got is records from '2019-05-23 00:00:00' - '2019-05-23 23:59:59'

Tried running it again at 8AM same date and the result is correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oops typo. I have edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little complicated.  The `current_date` is defined at the UTC date.  So, when you are calling it, the UTC date is "yesterday", and you are off by one day.

One way to fix this moves the current time into the time zone and then converts to a date:

```
WHERE date_field >= (current_timestamp at time zone 'Asia/Manila' - interval '1 day')::date AND
      date_field < (current_timestamp at time zone 'Asia/Manila')::date
```

Comment: It works  thanks, actually I tried it before and the output is wrong. Tried it again after reading your answer and the result without ::date is more than 16 hours , so I changed my config to use default timezone (UTC) as my application timezone ( automatically converts the query result to Asia Manila) instead of Manila. It looks like it is breaking my relative date query.